# Application form for lecturer position provides a template for an academic resume, should I follow that?

Tags: application, cv, faculty-application, lecturer

I am trying to apply for a Lecturer job in another country; I noticed that they're asking for an academic resume and they provided a template as well. Here is what they said:

> You should provide attachments, including your academic CV and details of research, publications and grants if not already covered (an Academic CV template is available here).

Here is the issue: the template has sections of stuff I didn't do or don't have. Since I completed my PhD in another country, we have different "evaluation metrics". For instance, in my country (3rd world country), it's pretty hard to find funding for your research, and most students do a PhD with no funding (my case). I do however have experience in preparing project proposals to get funding, but I never got funding. So, I don't know what to write in the "Research grants and contracts" section.

So my question is: is it a good idea to use my own template? The template they're providing is pretty detailed and they're asking for specific sections, such as contribution to the department, contribution to the faculty, contribution to the university and to enterprise. A resume is not an official document, meaning that the candidate makes his own resume and not some institution, am I right?

**Update:**

I want to thank all those who took the time to comment and answer my question.

I emailed the university and they said I can use my own template.

I want to clarify that the resume I have now (and I am using to apply for other opportunities) is not a representation of my lack of interest! I did re-format my resume a lot of times, in fact I used to prepare tailored resumes each time I apply (my field is cyber security and IA, so I did target vacancies that want a profile that unites the two fields, but I also applied for jobs that seeks individual skills). Before I apply, I always ask for external input from a professor in our lab about the resume I used. But I truly believe that it won't change a lot if another candidate has +5 years experience more than me and uses a generic format.

Even my supervisor noticed that and asked me to only use one, because according to her is "what's more important is the content of the resume and not how it looks". So, I prepared one standard resume that took me +3 hours!

Comment: *I emailed the university and they said I can use my own template.* Good, but the template will still indicate the information they want, even if you make yours look prettier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing in the statement ``(an Academic CV template is available here)'' indicating this is a required format.  I would assume that most applicants would not use the template.

I suspect the template is there to help applicants.  Does it have a place for hobbies?  If not, probably you want to not list hobbies.  It does have a place for ``contributions to the university'' so be sure it is clear on your CV if you ever sat on a campus-wide committee or some such thing. Different cultures put in different things in a CV, but in this case you have a guide.

The fact that the template has separate sections for different types of service makes me suspect this is a generic format used for scholars at many ranks and many departments. There may be many sections any specific person would have blank.

Comment: ThankYou.I do think it's a generic template,it was also posted in 2017 so it was there for sometime.But I am genuinely hesitant about the "contributions to the university" section.My university has a Computer Science department which handles EVERYTHING that falls even remotely to computer science.This makes it harder to have connection between researcher who works on specific field and the administration. Even in the same country,u might find a lot of differences between universities.So, in my opinion if their goal is to provide a generic format, then they should also provide generic sections.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that most of the applicants will use the template.  I also suspect that the search committee will expect all applicants' CVs to be in the same order.

If it were I, I'd use the template, omit entirely the things that aren't applicable in your case, and very briefly address those in a cover letter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, I did start the application process weeks ago and decided to drop it for this reason. I also believe they won't even consider my application since I have a PhD in another country (or continent if you may). I can get the same job with the same role and responsibilities in my country but I believe my application will be systematically dropped for this reason. So, I am still hesitant.

Comment: @U.User Your application is much more likely to be "systematically dropped" if you don't follow the process of the institution to which you are applying.  If the job is not worth reformatting your CV, well, you aren't very interested in it, eh?

Comment: I am HIGHLY interested. I've completed my PhD in mid-July, and since then I've applied to various research and teaching positions but I was never shortlisted for an interview. I stopped counting the times I've reformatted my resume. I know It's not supposed to be easy, but it's also a bit harder than the usual. Because of these special times, I started forming this idea of "being systematically dropped" or internal candidates are favored. But I do agree with you, I will never know If I don't try.

Comment: @BobBrown It is not very nice to assume that a candidate interested in a job should also be prepared to jump through all kind of administrative hoops, such as re-formatting the application pack and filling in forms which most of the selection panel members won't even bother reading. Academia needs great and creative people to do research and education, not office clerks to comply with exorbitant bureaucratic requirements.

Comment: @BobBrown I tend to agree with Dmitry to be honest. I think the OP sounds slightly nervous, not disinterested (indeed, see the "I am HIGHLY interested" assertion above). Nervous people tend to need a morale boost more than anything.

Comment: @U.User On that note, I think it's worth bearing in mind that a lot of academic life is just about getting better at dealing with repeated rejection (there's a lot of rejection in academia in practice). I think one aspect of that has to be to try to stop second guessing things and focus on the things you have some control over. If you're getting rejected a lot for something, try to find out why, but also try not to speculate on why without evidence - it's a waste of energy and can lead you to give up on things for no reason. Keep trying things, and learn how to react well to rejections.

Comment: See also this (if you want to cheer up): https://www.theguardian.com/education/2016/apr/30/cv-of-failures-princeton-professor-publishes-resume-of-his-career-lows

Comment: @Dmitry On the other hand, if you apply to so many faculty jobs that you can't take an hour to reformat your CV, there's something wrong.

Comment: @Stuart haha  "This darn CV of Failures has received way more attention than my entire body of academic work", I remember that I had a reputation of having "high number of paper rejections" in my lab, but I was also the first to defend his thesis from the team that joined the same year and even the team 1-2 years before me. So, I did develop the skill to deal with rejections, but you also know that in academia not all rejections are reasonable.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov  I did not "assume" that OP wasn't interested.  I remarked, or at least intended to, that OP's interest is reflected in the amount of effort he or she is willing to expend on the application.

Comment: @BobBrown Counting interest in "effort" is too simplistic and one-dimensional. For example, asking candidates to carve their application on stone blocks and deliver them in person would require even more effort, but is this an worthwhile effort? I doubt it. Reasonable policies and practices should aim to collect the necessary evidence with minimal costs for candidates and panel members.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov While in principle we would find some agreement, the ugly truth is that there are sometimes 500 applicants or more for 1 position.  So if the first cut is to weed out those failing some stupid bureaucratic procedure -- it may tend to weed out those who can't follow procedures for handling grants and/or students.  Also, there's this [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbard%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_theorem) that strongly suggests why committee choice is always such a messy process.

Comment: @U.User Sorry, didn't mean to imply that you hadn't developed that skill - was just trying to find something helpful to say. As to unreasonable rejections - I do think that most rejections have at least some nugget of reasonableness buried within them, and it's usually good to try to tease out what that is. For example, it's very hard to give a paper a scathing review without inadvertently leaking information that might help the authors fix it for next time. Which is to say, many rejections that are unreasonable also contain useful information, and extracting that is good.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz it was a good idea to ask this question, I've seen a lot of good comments and interesting opinions. I do agree with you, but also having a rejection doesn't necessarily imply that you made a mistake. For instance, I just read in the description of a job posting that if a candidate A from another country was selected for the job but later another candidate B in the same country showed potential, then they will proceed with candidate B instead. This is because the recruiter should justify (through some test) why they didn’t find a candidate that has the skills of candidate A

Comment: @U.User Yes, I'd agree that there are certainly situations when you can get rejected for something without really having made a mistake as such. I think my view is just that it's rare that you'll do anything absolutely perfectly, and a rejection is as good a time as any to take a look at what things you've done imperfectly in a particular situation so as to learn from that for the future. It also has the nice side-effect of distracting you from the rejection and making you focus on something potentially useful.

Answer (score 5):

Re-formatting the application pack for each vacancy is a huge waste of time. Some parts of it, such as the cover letter, may need to be adjusted to match the requirements of the vacancy. Other parts, such as CV, Publication List, Research statement, Teaching statement, etc, reflect your current profile. A University which asks these documents to be re-formatted for them is putting a huge additional burden on applicants. This is largely a test in compliance with bureaucratic requirements, than a test of your academic skills and abilities. It's up to you to decide whether the job is worth participating in such a test.

Outside academia, e.g. in IT sector, companies are searching for the candidates based on their online profiles, e.g. LinkedIn. All necessary details are clarified via interviews over the phone, skype/zoom or in person. Companies which expect developers to re-format CVs for them will likely go bust very quickly.

Comment: If I had typed my CV on the L.C. Smith typewriter I used as an undergraduate, I certainly wouldn't re-do it.  I could paste the various parts of my own CV into someone's template in ten minutes or so with Word or Libre Office.

The amount of effort one should/must put into applying for a job depends upon how much one wants the job, but also on how much competition there is for that job.  In the United States, and in many or perhaps most disciplines, there's more competition for academic jobs than for IT jobs.

Comment: Preparing tailored resumes for each job is not fun when you know you will receive an automated email with no feedback. I've seen positive and negative emails and they're basically the same. What I'm trying to say is if a candidate is expected to put extra-work to prepare a fancy and tailored resume for a company, then the company should put an extra-effort for a personalized response (positive or negative). Right now, HR department will go extra with you if they're only interested regardless of the effort you showed. I'm not saying don't try at all, and that's really flawed in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> specific sections, such as contribution to the department,
> contribution to the faculty, contribution to the university and to
> enterprise

They're all standard for **academic CVs** and if the institution has included them on its  template they reflect the criteria against which your application *will* be assessed.

Comment: The standard is  1) Contact Information 2)Research Objective or Personal Profile
    3) Education 4) Professional Appointments 5) Publications 6) Awards and Honors
    7) Grants and Fellowships 8) Conferences 9) Teaching Experience 10) Research Experience 11) Additional Activities 12) Languages and Skills 13) References. I agree that since it is mentioned it will be used as a criterion to assess my application. I think it's a good idea to follow the template!

Comment: In some countries, academic institutions are not organised exactly in the same way as in the U.S. For example, there may be no faculties or departments. This makes it much harder for applicants from these countries to complete an over-structured template. Effectively this "template" disadvantages applicants from these less represented backgrounds.

Answer (score -2):

I've always found that typesetting a CV well (getting page beaks in sensible places, preventing different bits of text from being printed one on top of the other, preventing lines from sticking off the edge of the page...) is difficult and stressful.  You could take it that, by providing a template file (as long as that template file is a good one), the university is offering to do a lot of that hard work for you, and protect you from that stress.  I wouldn't be inclined to turn that offer down.

Comment: OP already has their CV prepared from their other applications. Re-formatting it to match the University's own template will cost extra time and likely cause extra errors. This "offer" is not helpful for most applicants.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Yeah, on reflection I think my experience might be unique and not generalizable to other users.  (My experience being that, every time I edit a few words in my CV, e.g. to account for some new skill I've developed, I have to spend three-quarters of an hour fiddling with the formatting _within my existing template_ to get rid of all the daft pagination, bits of text printed superimposed on each other, and lines of text that don't fit within the horizontal width of the page.)